# How to tell if a particular day of the year has already passed?

Tags: c#, xaml, datetime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a TextBlock, and I would like to do a check on the date of the phone.
For example: "If passed April 10, displays a string, or do other .."
 This possibility exists with the class DateTime?

Comment: Do you mean April 10th of *this year*, or something like if the date is between January 1st and April 10th do something, if between April 11th and December 31st do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading your question right, you should be able to just do this:

```
if (DateTime.Today > yourTestDate)
{
    //do stuff.
}
```

Comment: This should be `DateTime.Today` as otherwise it will return true if the test date is today.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the date you wish to query into a `DateTime` object using `DateTime.TryParse` and then use `DateTime.Now.Subtract` to subtract this date. If you get a postive number in any of the properties such as Seconds, the date has passed. Negative number means it's in the future